# Not able to understand how PriorityQueue is changing the sort order?

Tags: java, collections

```
import java.util.*;
class abc {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();

        pq.add(1);
        pq.add(2);
        pq.add(3);
        pq.add(4);
        pq.add(5);
        pq.add(6);

        System.out.println(pq);
        pq.remove();
        System.out.println(pq);     
    }           
}
```

When I remove the element, order changes.
Output should be in ascending order according to lexicographical sorting. But I am getting output as:

[image: output]

Answer (score 3):

Calling `System.out.println(pq);` is the same as calling `System.out.println(pq.toString());`

If you look at the [documentation of the the toString() method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString()), you'll see that it states:

> Returns a string representation of this collection. The string
>   representation consists of a list of the collection's elements **in the
>   order they are returned by its iterator**, enclosed in square brackets
>   ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by the characters ", " (comma
>   and space). Elements are converted to strings as by
>   String.valueOf(Object).

I highlighted the important part. So we need to have a look the the [documentation of the iterator of the priority queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#iterator()) which states:

> Returns an iterator over the elements in this queue. **The iterator does
>   not return the elements in any particular order.**

So the output of your code does not allow any conclusions of the order imposed by the priority queue.

In the [main documentation of the PriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) it says:

> The Iterator provided in method iterator() is not guaranteed to
>   traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order.
>   If you need ordered traversal, consider using
>   Arrays.sort(pq.toArray()).

Answer (score 3):

`PriorityQueue` implements a Heap data structure. This data structure has the property to keep your elements **partially** sorted. Heap is a binary tree (even if in practice it's implemented in an array) that maintain the following invariance: If the node P has a child C, the value of P is smaller/bigger than the value of C.

Therefore only the first element (the root) is guaranteed to be the minimum/maximum of the collections, while all the other values are only partially sorted.

Why do that? Well, if you have to keep a completed sorted collection, the insert/delete operations will take `O(n)`, while with an heap data structure they both are `O(log n)`. If you're only interested in the max/min of the collection, then `PriorityQueue` has a significant advantage over a completed sorted array.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of [`AbstractCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString--)'s `toString()` method (which is invoked when you pass your queue to the `System.out.println()` method):

> The string representation consists of a list of the collection's
>   elements **in the order they are returned by its iterator**, [...]

From the documentation of [`PriorityQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#iterator--)'s `iterator()` method:

> Returns an iterator over the elements in this queue. The iterator does
>   **not return the elements in any particular order**.

There's your answer right there.